Iterate Over an Output Directory within a Model - QGIS Modeler
I am running a simple model that seems to have issues with larger file sizes. In order to remedy this I am looking to split the layer by attribute before processing, then merging the results. However I cannot seem to find a simple way to iterate over a folder like is possible in ArcGIS.


You can execute Split vector layer manually, then run the model in batch mode to process each file in the folder. Then Merge all outputs manually

If you are familiar with PyQGIS, you could export your model as a Python script and modify it so that it iterates through the specified directory, reads all files as QgsVectorLayer, and uses them as input to the 'Merge vector layers' algorithm. That could look something like this:
import os
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
import processing

directory = 'C:/Geodaten/test'
layers = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.shp'):
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(filepath, filename, 'ogr')
        layers.append(layer)


merged_layer = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {
        'LAYERS': input_layers,
        'CRS': None,
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
        })['OUTPUT']

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged_layer)



This seems to be something like what I was looking for. Would it be simple to modify this to run as a standalone python script and then insert it as an algorithm in the model?

In the QGIS Processing Toolbox, you can select 'Create new script from template.' Create such a script and edit the processAlgorithm method to merge the layers in the directory (using the code snippet I provided). Save this script. It should be available in the Model Designer now.

The issue here is that I want to split the vector layers by a field value from the previous functions and then iterate the remaining algorithms over each new geopackage. I would need to then merge the end result.
